# Class cast errors when sending JSON data via Advanced Rest Client

Tags: java, json, rest, neo4j

I am using the Advanced Rest Client tool to test a server side java class that processes data sent in as a json object and am encountering an error that has me stumped.  After much Google searches and trial and error attempts, I now turn to SO.

Some details on the problem.

-> Below is the test data being passed into the java class.  The data is in a valid format
   - verified the data via a validation tool.

```
[{ "Id":1,"Question":"What is the capital of Texas", "QuestionType":"SingleChoice",
"Options":[{ "Answer":1,"City":"Austin"}, { "Answer":2, "City":"Houston" }, { 
"Answer":3, "City":"El Paso" }] }]
```

-> I am using the Post option on the Advanced Rest Client tool.

-> application/json is the type used for this post.

-> the server side class is to post information to a Neo4J database and thus the Neo4J
   server is being used.  The server is up and running and I am able to send other
   transactions to other classes with no issues.

-> when I send the transaction using the above data-set, I encounter the below error...

```
message: "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
exception: "BadInputException"
fullname: "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.BadInputException"
stacktrace: [6]
  0:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.JsonFormat.readMap(JsonFormat.java:92)"
  1:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.
        readParameterList(RepresentationFormat.java:97)"
  2:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.
       invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)"
  3:  "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
  4:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.
      TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)"
  5:  "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" -
  cause: {
    message: "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
    exception: "ClassCastException"
    stacktrace: [7]
  0:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.JsonHelper.jsonToMap(JsonHelper.java:53)"
  1:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.formats.JsonFormat.readMap(JsonFormat.java:88)"
  2:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationFormat.
        readParameterList(RepresentationFormat.java:97)"
  3:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.
         invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)"
  4:  "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"
  5:  "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.
      TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)"
   6:  "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"
      -
      fullname: "java.lang.ClassCastException" 
  }
```

With the above in mind, I am leaning towards to error being encountered at the Advanced Rest Client tool level and not by the java class.  The reason for that is when a name of a non-existent class is used on the call, I get the same error.

Nor sure what other information can be provided to help resolve this.  Please let me know if you need additional details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take back my comment on the issue being on the Advanced Rest Client seeing the Neo4j server is issuing the errors.  That said, I am still where I was a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  Removing the outer brackets ([ ]) did the trick.  Doing so had the data encased by the {} brackets state that a JSON object is being sent (I believe).